# How to detect windows sleep in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, winapi

I have a small Node.js app which is running as a service with NSSM. I need to catch if windows is going to sleep and run a small quick code.

There is some powerMonitor in electron but I don't want to include a whole electron for this.

So I am thinking on other options and found that it would be possible to use RegisterPowerSettingNotification for this using ffi-napi.

I am trying this code but not able to get it to work, somehow need to add the callback to be  called I believe.

```js
const ffi = require('ffi-napi');
const ref = require('ref-napi');

const user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
  'RegisterPowerSettingNotification': ['pointer', ['pointer', 'pointer', 'int']]
});

const GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE = ref.allocCString('{98a7f580-01f7-48aa-9c0f-44352c29e5C0}');
const DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE = 0x00000000;

const callback = ffi.Callback('void', ['pointer', 'pointer'], (hRecipient, pPowerSetting) => {
  console.log('System is going to sleep');
});

const result = user32.RegisterPowerSettingNotification(null, GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
if (!result) {
  console.error('Failed to register for power setting notifications');
} else {
  console.log('Successfully registered for power setting notifications');
}

setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
```

It is registering successfully but still needs some work. Wondering if anyone can help on this?

Comment: You already asked the same question and removed reference to chatGPT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037860/how-to-catch-if-the-system-is-going-to-sleep-in-node-js

Comment: Using [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-registerservicectrlhandlerexw "Register It!") to register a function [*HandlerEx*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex) to handle extended service control requests. For `RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hRecipient,GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE,DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE)`, *For services, the Flags parameter should be one, and the hRecipient parameter should be a SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE as returned from RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx*.

Answer (score 0):

As [Writing a ServiceMain Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/writing-a-servicemain-function) shows,

> The SvcMain function first calls the [RegisterServiceCtrlHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsvc/nf-winsvc-registerservicectrlhandlera)(or *RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx*)
> function to register the SvcCtrlHandler function as the service's
> Handler function and begin initialization.

Then you can call `RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hRecipient,GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE,DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE)`

> For services, the `Flags` parameter should be one, and the `hRecipient`
> parameter should be a `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` as returned from
> [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-registerservicectrlhandlerexa).